# Crystal report : display parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, report

In my crystal report I am giving from and to date as input through an aspx page.
Now, I want to display the from date in the report viewer. Please give the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add the parameter fields to the report's Report Header section.

If it is a date-range parameter, create a formula field with the following code:

```
ToText(Minimum({?Date Range}), "MM/dd/yyyy") + "-" + ToText(Maximum({?Date Range}), "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Add the formula field to the report' Report Header section.

Answer (score 0):

Add one From date parameter in the report and then you can do like below code:

`lRptClass.SetParameterValue("Fromdate", Fromdate`)

Comment: it is asking value during page load?

Comment: i don't understand u r asking or giving answer.

Comment: how to pass value from aspx page to a crystal report ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 1 parameter named From date in your `.rpt` file.Then drag and drop where you want it.
and in the code behind you have to pass the parameter like

```
Rpt.SetParameterValue("Fromdate", Fromdate)
```

THus your problem willbe solved...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Stored Proceedure then you can take parameter there via @toDate and @fromDate and when you connet your SP with report simply drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

1 - You get your date string: string myDate

2 - Then you  converted myDate to a DateTime:
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime (date_expedition);
3 - Finally, you add your parameter rpt.setParameterValue ("dateField", date);